# Nested groupby in DataFrame and aggregate multiple columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, nested, aggregate

I am trying to do nested groupby as follows:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2016-10-11', 1: '2016-10-11', 2: '2016-10-11', 3: '2016-10-11', 4: '2016-10-11',5: '2016-10-12'}, 'Stock': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC', 3: 'ABC', 4: 'ABC', 5: 'XYZ'}, 'Quantity': {0: 60,1: 50, 2: 40, 3: 30, 4: 20, 5: 10}, 'UiD':{0:1,1:1,2:1,3:2,4:2,5:3}, 'StartTime': {0: '08:00:00.241', 1: '08:00:00.243', 2: '12:34:23.563', 3: '08:14.05.908', 4: '18:54:50.100', 5: '10:08:36.657'}, 'Sign':{0:1,1:1,2:0,3:-1,4:0,5:-1}, 'leg1':{0:2,1:2,2:4,3:5,4:7,5:8}})
>>> df1
         Date  Quantity  Sign     StartTime Stock  UiD  leg1
0  2016-10-11        60     1  08:00:00.241   ABC    1     2
1  2016-10-11        50     1  08:00:00.243   ABC    1     2
2  2016-10-11        40     0  12:34:23.563   ABC    1     4
3  2016-10-11        30    -1  08:14.05.908   ABC    2     5
4  2016-10-11        20     0  18:54:50.100   ABC    2     7
5  2016-10-12        10    -1  10:08:36.657   XYZ    3     8
>>> dfg1=df1.groupby(['Date','Stock'])
>>> dfg1.apply(lambda x:x.groupby('UiD').first()).groupby(['Date','Stock']).apply(lambda x:np.sum(x['Quantity']))
Date        Stock
2016-10-11  ABC      90
2016-10-12  XYZ      10
dtype: int64
>>>
>>> dfg1['leg1'].sum()
Date        Stock
2016-10-11  ABC      20
2016-10-12  XYZ       8
Name: leg1, dtype: int64
```

So far so good. Now I am trying to concatenate the two results into a new DataFrame `df2` as follows:

```
>>> df2 = pd.concat([dfg1['leg1'].sum(), dfg1.apply(lambda x:x.groupby('UiD').first()).groupby(['Date','Stock']).apply(lambda x:np.sum(x['Quantity']))],axis=1)
                   0   1
Date       Stock        
2016-10-11 ABC    20  90
2016-10-12 XYZ     8  10
>>>
```

I am wondering if there is a better way to re-write following line in order to avoid repetition of `groupby(['Date','Stock'])`

```
dfg1.apply(lambda x:x.groupby('UiD').first()).groupby(['Date','Stock']).apply(lambda x:np.sum(x['Quantity']))
```

Also this fails if `['Date','Stock']` contains `'UiD'` as one of the keys or if `['Date','Stock']` is replaced by just `['UiD']`.

Comment: Please restate your question to be clearer. You want to groupby(['Date','Stock']), then a) take only the first record for each UiD and sum (aggregate) its Quantity, but also b) sum all leg1 values for that Date,Stock combination (not just the first-for-each-UiD). Is that right?

Answer (score 5):

Please restate your question to be clearer. You want to `groupby(['Date','Stock'])`, then:

1. take only the first record for each UiD and sum (aggregate) its
   Quantity, but also
2. sum **all** leg1 values for that Date,Stock
   combination (not just the first-for-each-UiD). Is that right?

Anyway you want to perform an aggregation (sum) on multiple columns, and yeah the way to avoid repetition of groupby(['Date','Stock']) is to keep one dataframe, not try to stitch together two dataframes from two individual aggregate operations. Something like the following (I'll fix it once you confirm this is what you want):

```
def filter_first_UiD(g):
    #return g.groupby('UiD').first().agg(np.sum)
    return g.groupby('UiD').first().agg({'Quantity':'sum', 'leg1':'sum'})

df1.groupby(['Date','Stock']).apply(filter_first_UiD)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I dealt with the last scenario of avoiding groupby to fail if `['Date','Stock']` contains `'UiD'` as one of the keys or if `['Date','Stock']` is replaced by just `['UiD']` is as follows:

```
>>> df2 = pd.concat([dfg1['leg1'].sum(), dfg1[].first() if 'UiD' in `['Date','Stock']` else dfg1.apply(lambda x:x.groupby('UiD').first()).groupby(['Date','Stock']).apply(lambda x:np.sum(x['Quantity']))],axis=1)
```

But more elegant solution is still an open question.